# "url = ( )" connection timeout when connected to proxied network

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried to find the right answer for my situation, but it seems it may not exists yet.

In my current training course (very beginner level) I have an exercise to get some weather json info from a url (Open Weather in this case). Currently, this is the only way I have been taught to do this:

```
url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+city+"&appid="+api_key

request = requests.get(url)
json = request.json()
print(json)
```

I have my "city" and "api_key" parameters set as instructed, and have been able to successfully run my code and get the json info when connected to my personal home network. However, when I connect to my work network, physically at the office or via VPN, I get this magical wall:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
line 169, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py",
line 96, in create_connection
    raise err   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py",
line 86, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa) TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
after a period of time, or established connection failed because
connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
line 394, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
line 234, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)   File
"C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1257,
in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line
1303, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1252,
in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line
1012, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 952, in
send
    self.connect()   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
line 200, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
line 181, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError( urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000255A4B11370>:
Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection
attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
after a period of time, or established connection failed because
connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests-2.26.0-py3.9.egg\requests\adapters.py",
line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py",
line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
HTTPConnectionPool(host='api.openweathermap.org', port=80): Max
retries exceeded with url:
/data/2.5/weather?q=*REDACTED*&appid=*REDACTED* (Caused by
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
0x00000255A4B11370>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
failed because connected host has failed to respond'))        

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"c:\Users\*REDACTED*\Training\Code\Python\weather.py", line 7, in
<module>
    request = requests.get(url)   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests-2.26.0-py3.9.egg\requests\api.py",
line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests-2.26.0-py3.9.egg\requests\sessions.py",
line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests-2.26.0-py3.9.egg\requests\sessions.py",
line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests-2.26.0-py3.9.egg\requests\adapters.py",
line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
HTTPConnectionPool(host='api.openweathermap.org', port=80): Max
retries exceeded with url:
/data/2.5/weather?q=*REDACTED*&appid=*REDACTED* (Caused by
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
0x00000255A4B11370>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
failed because connected host has failed to respond'))      PS
C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Training\Code\Python&
C:/Users/*REDACTED*/Python/Python39/python.exe
"c:/Users/*REDACTED*/Training/Code/Python/weather.py" Traceback (most
recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
line 169, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py",
line 96, in create_connection
    raise err   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py",
line 86, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa) TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
after a period of time, or established connection failed because
connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
line 394, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
line 234, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)   File
"C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1257,
in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line
1303, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1252,
in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line
1012, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 952, in
send
    self.connect()   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
line 200, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
line 181, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError( urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000229035A1370>:
Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection
attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
after a period of time, or established connection failed because
connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests-2.26.0-py3.9.egg\requests\adapters.py",
line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py",
line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
HTTPConnectionPool(host='api.openweathermap.org', port=80): Max
retries exceeded with url:
/data/2.5/weather?q=*REDACTED*&appid=*REDACTED* (Caused by
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
0x00000229035A1370>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
failed because connected host has failed to respond'))        

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"c:\Users\*REDACTED*\Training\Code\Python\weather.py", line 7, in
<module>
    request = requests.get(url)   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests-2.26.0-py3.9.egg\requests\api.py",
line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests-2.26.0-py3.9.egg\requests\api.py",
line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests-2.26.0-py3.9.egg\requests\sessions.py",
line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests-2.26.0-py3.9.egg\requests\sessions.py",
line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\*REDACTED*\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests-2.26.0-py3.9.egg\requests\adapters.py",
line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
HTTPConnectionPool(host='api.openweathermap.org', port=80): Max
retries exceeded with url:
/data/2.5/weather?q=*REDACTED*&appid=*REDACTED* (Caused by
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
0x00000229035A1370>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
failed because connected host has failed to respond'))
```

Quick ref of facts/actions taken:
-Tried setting the proxy globally to all Python instances via the `set proxy...` command.
-Not using a `venv`.
-Tried to add the `--proxy...` argument at the end of the command before executing via the the Visual Studio Code terminal.
-On Windows 10 Enterprise.

I am unable to move to the next module of the course because I need this code to work so that I know how to fix the error in the next set of codes I will have to do. I also apologize if this is a lot of words to get through (I am a noob for a reason, I guess), but I really appreciate anyone who could guide me.

Comment: Well, the error says that the host (`api.openweathermap.org`) takes too long to respond. Have you tried opening the URL (`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=<city>&appid=<appid>`) in your favorite Internet browser ? Also you could try to change the `http://` in the URL to `https://`.

Comment: @Programmer - I just tried your suggestion to opened the url in my browser and I get the json information I need for this demo. However, trying to replace "http" with "https" still results in the same error in the terminal.

Comment: Okay, that's something, In this case, try to [add a User-Agent header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47375332/14909980).

Comment: Also you can try setting the `timeout` parameter to a higher value, e.g. 5 or 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of a colleague, I was able to better interpret the link that [Сергей Зайков](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16686130/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2) referenced. It was a proxy issue after all.

After making my adjustment in the code, I was able to modify it by adding the lines below and updating the `request.get`

```
http_proxy = "http://*REDACTED*:8080"

proxyDict = {"http" : http_proxy}

request = requests.get(url, proxies=proxyDict)
```

I am now able to run my code as intended.

Answer (score 0):

For Requests proxy set in own manner [Proxies in Requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies)

Comment: Using this option gives me the same error wall listed in my question.