# Why am I seeing ``TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out`` using python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, http-headers, request-headers

I'm trying to write a simple script to crawl a website (respecting robots.txt and waiting 2secs between requests). For several sites I've tried this works fine but I'm getting stuck with one site (a client, so if the problem was e.g. cloudflare I could ask the web dev to maybe sort it for me).

I'm trying:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.westleyrichards.com'
response = requests.get(url)
```

but always seeing:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    168         try:
--> 169             conn = connection.create_connection(
    170                 (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     95     if err is not None:
---> 96         raise err
     97 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     85                 sock.bind(source_address)
---> 86             sock.connect(sa)
     87             return sock

TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

I usually use the following headers, as in `response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)`, I don't know if there is an extra header I should be using?

```
headers = {
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Expect': '100-continue',
            'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
            'DNT': '1',
            'TE': 'compress, deflate, gzip, trailers',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 12_0_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.0 Safari/605.1.15',
            'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
            'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
            'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
        }
```

My approach seems to work for every other site I try. I can easily navigate to the site in my browser (so it's not their server connection) and I can easily run this same code fine with other URLs (so it's not my connection or my python environment).

As an example:

```
urls = ['https://www.westleyrichards.com', 
        'https://en.wikipedia.org', 
        'https://theescooterco.com']

s = requests.Session()
s.headers = headers
for url in urls:
    print(url)
    try:
        response = s.get(url, timeout=0.5)
        print('\tstatus code: {}'.format(response.status_code))
        print('\thtml length: {}'.format(len(response.text)))
    except:
        print('\tTimeoutError')
    print('')
s.close()


### out ###

https://www.westleyrichards.com
    TimeoutError

https://en.wikipedia.org
    status code: 200
    html length: 83936

https://theescooterco.com
    status code: 200
    html length: 398885
```

Comment: Take a look at this post, it may help you understand this *error* a little further. **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47375153/requests-get-in-python-giving-connection-timeout-error**

Comment: Thanks @FishingCode, I think the OP there was not including 'user-agent' in the headers - I am doing this already but I wondered if there is some other header that might be needed. I don't know how to find what the server is wanting, I just know that it generally wants 'user-agent'.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the time-out length to more than *0.5*? This isn't a server domain issue either, since the site is loading. If that doesn't work, try this **response = s.get(url, headers = headers, timeout= 0.5)**.

Comment: The error (second code block in the question) appears when no timeout is used. It takes around 15 seconds and then gives the TimeoutError: [Errno 60]