# Web scraping for the website not working using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, timeout

My code just keeps running without any results

```
import requests
import  pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.cmegroup.com/markets/agriculture/livestock/pork-cutout.quotes.html'
Data = requests.get(url)
print (Data)
```

Comment: because you never print anything?

Comment: print statement will work if the code goes beyond the 'Data = requests.get(url)' statement. The code just keeps running and then gives a timeout error

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue with that site specifically requiring header information. I found a solution here that worked for me:

[requests.get in python giving connection timeout error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47375153/requests-get-in-python-giving-connection-timeout-error)

```
import requests
import  pandas as pd

headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'http://www.cmegroup.com/markets/agriculture/livestock/pork-cutout.quotes.html'
Data = requests.get(url, timeout=15, verify=False, allow_redirects=True,headers=headers)
print(Data.content)
```

Comment: Still getting error with the above code "TimeoutError: timed out"

Answer (score -1):

In this case, your program basically requests the page and then stores the requested data inside the Data variable. You do not do any processing on the variable after. In order to do something with it, you can do something like

```
print(Data)
```

This will show you what is inside the variable. You can also use a debugging tool such as those within vscode if you add a breakpoint there.

Comment: print statement will work if the code goes beyond the 'Data = requests.get(url)' statement. The code just keeps running and then gives a timeout error